# Spelling Errors on Free Teams Offering Dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Saw this right away.  I assume, like a résumé, you want this dialog to be perfect.

[image]

Comment: In other news, this is an insanely cool offering.  Perfect for combining with a free Trello account.

Comment: I poked the devs about this.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the report, Robert! This should be fixed now.